# How do you display all images coming from the newsapi?

Tags: javascript, html, api

Hi I am trying to create a news app using the newsapi. I have managed to display the headings from the api but cant seem to manage to loop over all the images and be displayed to the screen. If you could show me how this could be done I would very much appreciate this. my code is:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>News App</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<h2>BBC News</h2>
<span class="newsImage"></span>
<li class = newsList></li>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const newsList = document.querySelector(".newsList")
const newsImage = document.querySelector(".newsList")
newsImage.innerHTML =''
newsList.innerHTML= ''


var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
          'sources=bbc-news&' +
          'apiKey=**********************';
var req = new Request(url);
fetch(req)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
       }).then((data)=>{
           console.log(data)
           data.articles.map(article => {
               let li = document.createElement('li')
               let a = document.createElement('a')
               let image = document.createElement('span') 
               image.innerHTML = `<img src=${data.articles.urlToImage}>`
               a.setAttribute('href', article.url)
               a.setAttribute('target','_blank' )
               a.textContent = `${article.title}`
               li.appendChild(a)
               newsList.appendChild(li)
               newsImage.appendChild(image)

           });
       })
```

Comment: It is as simple as you missing quotes around the src?

````
image.innerHTML = `<img src="${data.articles.urlToImage}">`
````

Comment: I have tried what you have said, but the images still do not show up.

Comment: I also ran across this issue, no luck so far.

Comment: Some websites use cookies and some uses unknown cross origin blocking. So easy solution is that use copyright free images from other services related to that article.